# HTML Table dynamically generate columns using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table

Can you please help me generating HTML Table by using the JSON data with Angular ng-repeat.

***[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/6z3Ka4NjY3OcQcyE4LeE?p=preview)***

**JSON Data**

```
{
  "account": {
    "accountId": "54545",
    "premise": {
      "address": {
        "address1": "1800 Bishop Gate Boulevard",
        "address2": "Apartment 129",
        "city": "Mount Laurel",
        "province": "NJ",
        "postalCode": "08054",
        "country": "US",
        "direction": null,
        "externalReference": null,
        "verified": false
      },
      "timeZone": "US_EASTERN",
      "locale": "EN",
      "camera": [
        {
          "id": "175277.2",
          "name": "camera1",
          "macAddress": "00:0E:8F:5B:AB:88",
          "manufacturer": "gabreal",
          "model": "iCamera",
          "serialNumber": "000E8F5BAB88",
          "firmwareVersion": "3.0.01.07",
          "hardwareVersion": null
        },
        {
          "id": "175277.3",
          "name": "camera2",
          "macAddress": "D4:21:22:D9:D0:73",
          "manufacturer": "gabreal",
          "model": "iCamera2-C",
          "serialNumber": "D42122D9D073",
          "firmwareVersion": "3.0.02.39",
          "hardwareVersion": null
        },
        {
          "id": "175277.1",
          "name": "camera3",
          "macAddress": "00:0E:8F:95:A8:A6",
          "manufacturer": "gabreal",
          "model": "SerComm_Camera_8021",
          "serialNumber": "000E8F95A8A6",
          "firmwareVersion": "1.0.24",
          "hardwareVersion": null
        }
      ],
      "thermostat": [
        {
          "id": "0024460000084172.10",
          "name": "Thermostat1",
          "type": "THERMOSTAT",
          "manufacturer": "RTCOA",
          "serialNumber": null,
          "firmwareVersion": "0x00000587",
          "hardwareVersion": "192",
          "model": "CT30S"
        },
        {
          "id": "000d6f0003ec6669.1",
          "name": "Thermostat2",
          "type": "THERMOSTAT",
          "manufacturer": "CentraLite Systems",
          "serialNumber": null,
          "firmwareVersion": "0x1418468c",
          "hardwareVersion": "2",
          "model": "3156105"
        }
      ],
      "zone": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "one",
          "type": "DOOR",
          "functionType": "ENTRY_EXIT",
          "sensor": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "type": "DRY_CONTACT",
              "sourceType": "ZIGBEE",
              "serialNumber": "000d6f00030cdbcf.1",
              "model": "MCT-320 SMA",
              "manufacturer": "Visonic",
              "firmwareVersion": "0x00040008",
              "hardwareVersion": "1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Motion",
          "type": "MOTION",
          "functionType": "INTERIOR_FOLLOWER",
          "sensor": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "type": "MOTION",
              "sourceType": "ZIGBEE",
              "serialNumber": "000d6f0004b2af93.1",
              "model": "NEXT K85 SMA",
              "manufacturer": "Visonic",
              "firmwareVersion": "0x0004000b",
              "hardwareVersion": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "cpe": {
        "cpeId": "9c972684b2ca",
        "name": null,
        "deploymentModel": "WIFI_CLIENT_PSK_2_MODE",
        "serialNumber": null,
        "manufacturer": "Technicolor",
        "model": "TCA203",
        "hardwareRev": "5",
        "passPhrase": "528233",
        "cellularProfileName": null,
        "imeiNumber": 359942045924230,
        "iccId": "89011703258034552401",
        "simCardPhoneNumber": null,
        "simCardAccountNumber": null,
        "wifiMacAddress": "70:25:59:79:E2:EE",
        "firmwareVersion": "7_3_8_050000_201611152386",
        "widget": [
          {
            "name": "com.wsi.android.Gabreal",
            "version": "1.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "com.icontrol.apps.clock",
            "version": "1.0.0.0.3"
          }
        ],
        "module": []
      },
      "premiseId": null
    },
    "source": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

**The table I want to generate as below**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Property<br></th>
    <th>camera</th>
    <th>camera</th>
    <th>camera</th>
    <th>thermostat</th>
    <th>thermostat</th>
    <th>sensor</th>
    <th>sensor</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>175277.2</td>
    <td>175277.3</td>
    <td>175277.1</td>
    <td>0024460000084172.10</td>
    <td>000d6f0003ec6669.1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>camera1</td>
    <td>camera2</td>
    <td>camera3</td>
    <td>Thermostat1</td>
    <td>Thermostat2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>macAddress</td>
    <td>00:0E:8F:5B:AB:88</td>
    <td>D4:21:22:D9:D0:73</td>
    <td>00:0E:8F:95:A8:A6</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>manufacturer</td>
    <td>gabreal</td>
    <td>gabreal</td>
    <td>gabreal</td>
    <td>RTCOA</td>
    <td>CentraLite Systems</td>
    <td>Visonic</td>
    <td>Visonic</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Note :** Aruna has answered the question, but it fails when there different type JSON Object like zone object is different from others.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/zN1KJKqZrBjMsqySkYtC?p=preview    .....not sure if this is the most efficicent way of doing but this could definitely give you a headstart

Comment: Anirudh I dont want to write this way because I just written simple JSON to know the logic. Actually my json has lot of objects like Camera and Thermostat. I want to loop through all the Objects and get the details.

Comment: @Batman Can you check the below solution. It's generic with the objects. Only name and id properties are hard coded

Comment: @cale_b please check the question I have clearly mentioned the demo i have tried [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/tT2ltDz2TquKHjIE8OKD?p=preview)

Comment: Copy the relevant code in to your question.

Comment: Updated now with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `generic` solution with the object and the properties.

*Updated as per the `json` change on the Bounty request.*

```js
var app = angular.module('studentApp', []);

app.controller('StudentCntrl', function($scope,$http) {
    //$http.get('data.json').then(function (response){
               //console.log(response.data.pages);
                //$scope.deviceInfo = response.data.account.premise;
        //});
  
var responseData = {
  "account": {
    "accountId": "54545",
    "premise": {
      "address": {
        "address1": "1800 Bishop Gate Boulevard",
        "address2": "Apartment 129",
        "city": "Mount Laurel",
        "province": "NJ",
        "postalCode": "08054",
        "country": "US",
        "direction": null,
        "externalReference": null,
        "verified": false
      },
      "timeZone": "US_EASTERN",
      "locale": "EN",
      "camera": [
        {
          "id": "175277.2",
          "name": "camera1",
          "macAddress": "00:0E:8F:5B:AB:88",
          "manufacturer": "gabreal",
          "model": "iCamera",
          "serialNumber": "000E8F5BAB88",
          "firmwareVersion": "3.0.01.07",
          "hardwareVersion": null
        },
        {
          "id": "175277.3",
          "name": "camera2",
          "macAddress": "D4:21:22:D9:D0:73",
          "manufacturer": "gabreal",
          "model": "iCamera2-C",
          "serialNumber": "D42122D9D073",
          "firmwareVersion": "3.0.02.39",
          "hardwareVersion": null
        },
        {
          "id": "175277.1",
          "name": "camera3",
          "macAddress": "00:0E:8F:95:A8:A6",
          "manufacturer": "gabreal",
          "model": "SerComm_Camera_8021",
          "serialNumber": "000E8F95A8A6",
          "firmwareVersion": "1.0.24",
          "hardwareVersion": null
        }
      ],
      "thermostat": [
        {
          "id": "0024460000084172.10",
          "name": "Thermostat1",
          "type": "THERMOSTAT",
          "manufacturer": "RTCOA",
          "serialNumber": null,
          "firmwareVersion": "0x00000587",
          "hardwareVersion": "192",
          "model": "CT30S"
        },
        {
          "id": "000d6f0003ec6669.1",
          "name": "Thermostat2",
          "type": "THERMOSTAT",
          "manufacturer": "CentraLite Systems",
          "serialNumber": null,
          "firmwareVersion": "0x1418468c",
          "hardwareVersion": "2",
          "model": "3156105"
        }
      ],
      "zone": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "one",
          "type": "DOOR",
          "functionType": "ENTRY_EXIT",
          "sensor": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "type": "DRY_CONTACT",
              "sourceType": "ZIGBEE",
              "serialNumber": "000d6f00030cdbcf.1",
              "model": "MCT-320 SMA",
              "manufacturer": "Visonic",
              "firmwareVersion": "0x00040008",
              "hardwareVersion": "1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Motion",
          "type": "MOTION",
          "functionType": "INTERIOR_FOLLOWER",
          "sensor": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "type": "MOTION",
              "sourceType": "ZIGBEE",
              "serialNumber": "000d6f0004b2af93.1",
              "model": "NEXT K85 SMA",
              "manufacturer": "Visonic",
              "firmwareVersion": "0x0004000b",
              "hardwareVersion": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "cpe": {
        "cpeId": "9c972684b2ca",
        "name": null,
        "deploymentModel": "WIFI_CLIENT_PSK_2_MODE",
        "serialNumber": null,
        "manufacturer": "Technicolor",
        "model": "TCA203",
        "hardwareRev": "5",
        "passPhrase": "528233",
        "cellularProfileName": null,
        "imeiNumber": 359942045924230,
        "iccId": "89011703258034552401",
        "simCardPhoneNumber": null,
        "simCardAccountNumber": null,
        "wifiMacAddress": "70:25:59:79:E2:EE",
        "firmwareVersion": "7_3_8_050000_201611152386",
        "widget": [
          {
            "name": "com.wsi.android.Gabreal",
            "version": "1.2"
          },
          {
            "name": "com.icontrol.apps.clock",
            "version": "1.0.0.0.3"
          }
        ],
        "module": []
      },
      "premiseId": null
    },
    "source": "INTERNAL"
  }
};
  
var headerProperty = $scope.headerProperty = 'deviceType';
  
rebuildDeviceInfo(responseData);
  
function rebuildDeviceInfo(data) {
  var deviceInfoData = responseData.account.premise;
  var deviceInfo = [], deviceProperties = [];
  
  // Parse devices
  angular.forEach(deviceInfoData, function(devices, deviceKey) {
    if(angular.isArray(devices)) {
       deviceInfo = deviceInfo.concat(parseDevices(devices, deviceKey));
    }
  });
  
  // Parse device properties
  for(var i = 0; i < deviceInfo.length; i++) {
    var device = deviceInfo[i];
    angular.forEach(device, function(value, deviceProperty) {
      if(deviceProperties.indexOf(deviceProperty) === -1) {
        deviceProperties.push(deviceProperty);
      }
    });
  }
  
  $scope.deviceInfo = deviceInfo;
  $scope.deviceProperties = deviceProperties;
}
  
function parseDevices(dataArray, dataKey) {
     var deviceInfo = [];
     if(angular.isArray(dataArray)) {
       for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
         var data = dataArray[i];
         if(data.hasOwnProperty('manufacturer') || data.hasOwnProperty('model')) {
           data[headerProperty] = dataKey;
           deviceInfo.push(data);
         } else {
            angular.forEach(data, function(devices, deviceKey) {
              if(angular.isArray(devices)) {
                 deviceInfo = deviceInfo.concat(parseDevices(devices, deviceKey));
              }
            });
         }
       }
     }
    
     return deviceInfo;
}
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="studentApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script  src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="StudentCntrl">

 
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Property</th>
              <th ng-repeat="device in deviceInfo track by $index">{{device[headerProperty]}}</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <tr ng-repeat="prop in deviceProperties track by $index" ng-if="prop != headerProperty">
                <td>{{prop}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="device in deviceInfo track by $index">{{device[prop]}}</td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Aruna !! is there a way we can achieve this using setRows() and setHeaders() .. Upvoted :)

Comment: @Batman, Sorry, can you please explain me what it means `using setRows() and setHeaders()` since the code has this already. Within your `$http` code, you can just call setData(response.data)` and that's it. Please explain me

Comment: @cale_b I thought he has tried with few `ng-repeat` inside the html in the Demo url, `https://plnkr.co/edit/tT2ltDz2TquKHjIE8OKD?p=preview`

Comment: @cale_b I am not asking to write code here . I am asking to help with Approach

Comment: @Aruna Yeah just wanted to know like instead of setHeader() is there way in AngulaJS we can get the Object name

Comment: @Batman Usually, headers and number of columns will be static and row count will be dynamic. But for this case, headers and number of columns are dynamic and row count is static. That's why we have to rebuild the object. What I can do is, instead of two methods, I can try to reduce as one method.

Comment: Thanks Aruna That will be helpful because in my JSON i have so many different objects otherthan Camera, thermostat and also so may fields other than id and name so

Comment: @Batman I have updated the code with just one method. If you have so many fields and the order of the row for those fields are not matter then I can make all of them generic without hard coding. Just tell me what are the fields.

Comment: id,name,macAddress,manufacturer,model,serialNumber,firmwareVersion,hardwareVersion @Aruna these are the fields

Comment: @Batman You can check the code now which is purely generic. I have added the first column as property name to identify which property it is.

Comment: Thanks Aurna !! Now I understood the logic :) and accepted answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129442/discussion-between-batman-and-aruna).

Comment: I have editted the post with Bounty to get better answer since i am not able to get the table for updated JSON. If i am not getting better answer, I am allotting 50 bounty to you. can you please look into my new JSON and help here. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Batman I have updated the generic and more cleaner answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks @Aruna !! worked like a charm I need another 19 hours to award bounty will do ..